# Are adapters unsafe? Plug G to plug F (UK to Sweden)

Tags: electrical, adapter

I'm thinking of buying an instant pot ( https://www.instantpot.co.uk/product/instant-pot-duo-8-litre-electric-pressure-cooker-220v/ ).

It's a UK version and I live in Sweden. The voltage and frequency seems to be the same (around 220-230V and 50Hz).

I know I need to buy an adapter to make it fit in the socket.

**My question:** is it dangerous to use adapters like this (not to convert the voltage or anything), simply to make it fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm thinking of buying an instant pot

The good news is that the specifications for that instant pot say it comes with both UK and Schuko power cables. So you shouldn't need to adapt anything.

> Are adapters unsafe?

There are a few issues with adaptors.

1. There are a lot of *really* shoddy adapters out there.
2. Many adaptors do not provide an earth connection.
3. Many adapters try to generalise supporting multiple plug and/or socket types, but at the expense of a looser fit and/or a smaller contact area.
4. Many adapters have a lower current rating than the sockets they adapt between.
5. The extra weight and leverage puts more stress on the socket.

If it's a well-made adaptor that has correctly sized (4.8mm not 4mm) pins, the correct Schuko retention features, an intact earth path, a sufficient current rating and a socket designed specifically to take a BS1363 plug then it's probably safe enough but still for long-term use I would always favour changing the plug or cord over using an adapter.

Also be aware that Schuko plugs are unpolarised, so live and neutral may end up swapped. For modern equipment built to IEC standards this shouldn't be an issue but for vintage equipment or home-built stuff it may be.

Answer (score 0):

In UK they use socket G and Sweden is socket F the voltage is compatible with Sweden's power grid so if you have a friend that is an electrician they should be able to replace that socket with an F plug. I don't recommend doing that unless you know how to do it. Hooking a plug wrong would kill you.

https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/

And of course you could get an adapter but an instant pot amp draw might be to much for the adapter. You need to verify how many amps the adapter can handle.

Thanks

Comment: When you say converter what do you mean? I just need an adapter, i.e a device which I plug my instant pot into, which then goes into the wall right? What could happen if the instant pot draws too much amp for the adapter? Fire hazard?

Comment: Yes if too much amp draw over the adapter depending of the specs of the adapter could cause a fire.

Answer (score 0):

An adaptor will be fine.  The pot is 1200W, so it will draw about 4 to 5 amps in normal operation.

If you have no plans to visit the UK, I would cut the plug off and fit a Swedish plug.  (Obviously don't do that if you don't know how, but it's really straightforward - ask if you need instructions.)

There is one other point: The pot you link to says that it comes with both UK and Schuko plugs.  "Schuko" is a another term for a Type-F plug - so there may be nothing to do at all.